# Is it possible to get the id of the clicked Element Cefsharp?

Tags: c#, html, cefsharp

I want that if a user clicks on the button with the id="test" the destop programm does something, so I tried it with the onBeforeBrowse Methode but there I can only check if the URL is something. Is it possible to do the same with a Id?

Comment: Start from the beginning,  what exactly are you trying to achieve?  What do you need the element ID for?

Comment: I want that if a user clicks on a button inside the browser viewport that a new form2 opens.

Comment: How does the id help you open a new form? I need to know specific details otherwise I cannot recommend a solution. `OnBeforeBrowse` has no direct access to an elements Id.

Comment: So I want to make the App in my Webbrowser because it is easier for me, but I also want that if a user clicks on a HTML-Element that for example a shortcut is created on the destop of the user or a Form and so on. So basically I want that a webbrowser-Element click effects the installed programm, so I want to check with Cefsharp if the clicked Element has the Id="test", then create a shortcut on the destop of the user.

Comment: The simplest option is to execute some JavaScript to capture the click event of the link and append the element ID to the query string. Alternatively you can use PostMessage to communicate with your .net application see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent